# Unity iOS link.xml location

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

To strip unused code in iOS builds with IL2CPP backend, Unity offers the option to "Strip Engine Code".
The documentation for stopping unwanted strips can be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html), but I didn't find any advise, where to put the link.xml.

So where does it have to be? In the Assets folder? Do I have to "activate" it in some way, or is it automatically used, when it sits at the correct path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really dislike the Unity documentation sometimes.

[Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TroubleShootingIPhone.html) it says:

> The stripping process can be customized by adding a custom link.xml
>   file to the Assets folder of your Unity project.

and there no mentioning of "activating" it in any way, so it's probably used automatically.

Comment: Is that has to be in `Assets` root? Can I put it in `Assets/Plugins/MyAwesomePlugin/link.xml`?

Comment: Yes @RichardFu, you can put the file anywhere in your project

Comment: you can only put `link.xml` in the ```Assets``` folder or any subdirectory of Assets. see [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP-BytecodeStripping.html)

Answer (score 1):

based on [Unity's Document](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP-BytecodeStripping.html), you can put `link.xml` anywhere in the Assets folder.

> creating a link.xml file and placing it into the Assets folder (or any subdirectory of Assets).